# Ask for login only on wake up/reboot?

Tags: windows-11

In all previous Windows versions there was a setting that when enabled would lock system when screen timeout. In Windows 11 I can't find any such settings. I can control screen timeout, but that actually locks the system and doesn't turn off the screen (WTF!). The screen turns off much later after lock screen was shown.

I have this setting enabled, but it still asks for login after few minutes of inactivity.
[image]

There is no additional setting for the system lock timeout:

[image]

**How do I make the system ask for login *ONLY* when it wakes up from sleep or after reboot?**

Basically, I want the screen turn off after 1 minute. Before computer goes to sleep, if interacted, it would simply turn on the screen without login, and after 1 hour of inactivity put it to sleep, then ask for login when it wakes up.

So far I've tried:

set `NoLockscreen` to `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`

Set `Attributes` to `2` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8ec4b3a5-6868-48c2-be75-4f3044be88a7`, which shows new option `Console lock display off timeout` in Power Options screen under display:

[image]

Screensaver is set to none:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for screen saver settings? Set it to none (black screen), set Wait:1 minute, and make sure "On resume, display logon screen" is not checked

Comment: `Console lock display off timeout` defines how long to keep the display powered on, *after* it has been locked. Should probably change to 1 minute

Comment: It was set to none an checkbox unchecked (I've updated the question)